# Creating simple password cracker using numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm Trying to create a (number) password cracker function using numpy arrays instead of for-loops.

What can I add to my cracker function to avoid this error? (See image of code attached)

[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv8JP.png)

I want the cracker function to return the value in the 'possible' array that returns 'Correct' when used as the argument in the password function.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors/text.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do not post pictures of your code, for future reference. Paste and format it so that another user can copy it and help you easily.

---

What you need is to apply the function `password()` on every element of the array `possible`, and to return the index where the value is correct. The simplest way would be to do it with a loop:

```
def cracker(testrange):
    possible = np.linspace(0, testrange, testrange + 1, dtype=int)
    results = [p for p in possible if password(p) == "Correct"]
    if len(results):
        return results[0]
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use numpy's `vectorize` function:

```
def cracker(testrange):
    possible = np.linspace(0, testrange, testrange + 1, dtype=int)
    results = possible[np.vectorize(password)(possible) == "Correct"]
    if len(results):
        return results[0]
```

#### Explanation

Simply put, the function you had, `password`, takes a single number, checks it, and returns a single output. But you need to do this not for just a single number, but a whole array of numbers (`possible`).  [np.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) helps you do exactly this; it is no different from a for loop. I will further break down the steps in `results = possible[np.vectorize(password)(possible) == "Correct"]`:

```
check_passwords = np.vectorize(password)
# check_passwords is now a new function which will work on an array.
# Basically it is like running the old function password() multiple
# times inside a loop

output = check_passwords(possible)
# array containing ['Incorrect', 'Incorrect', ... , 'Correct', ... , 'Incorrect']

position = output == 'Correct'
# array containing [False, False, ... , True, ... , False]

result = possible[output]
# gives the elements of possible which was 'Correct'

return result[0]
```

Comment: np.vectorise is new to me. Could you explain why you have used it here?/what is happening in the following line:  results = possible[np.vectorize(password)(possible) == "Correct"]. I especially don't understand why the two brackets (password) and (possible) are directly next to eachother without issue: what is np.vectorize taking as its argument?

Comment: I've edited in an explanation below. Vectorize is the same thing as a loop, just useful for writing neater code in certain scenarios.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks for the help. I now see the usefulness of this function

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to my way

```
def password(correctedpassword):
    if 13 in correctedpassword:
        return "Correct"
    else:
        return "Incorrect"
    
def cracker(testrange):
    possible = np.linspace(0,testrange,testrange+1)
    return password(possible)
```

Output when call function cracker(100):

```
'Correct'
```

Output when call function cracker(12):

```
'Incorrect'
```